# Django, best way to print a field key

Tags: django, label, field

I want to print fields of a model differently than by first_name
I want to print something like "key: value" but it prints "first_name: Georges", I would prefer that it's looks like "First name: Georges"

Currently i'm using a file named form.html that I include in every form template:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% for field in form %}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ field.label_tag }}

    {% if form.is_bound %}
      {% if field.errors %}
        {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ error }}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
      {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if field.help_text %}
      <small class="form-text text-muted">
        {{ field.help_text }}
      </small>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And a model that looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

What is the best way to print first_name as "First name"?:

Is it by setting verbose_name for every fields in the models.py?

Or by setting label in the forms.py for every fields in each form?

Or by not using a dynamic template and hardcode it in my form.html?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/ <--- Label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what Aleksei Maide said to change that you need to alter the Label, here is an example:

in your form class add a method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourFormName, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'].label = "First name"
```

this is how i'm displaying it in my template:

```
<label class="bmd-label-static">{{ field.label }}</label>
{{ field.name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think by a moment that you have a Model Form with 30 fields, and as this form, you have other 30 more Model Forms, now, you have to set every time your field labels, is a very complicated task, don't you think?

i could suggest you that use the *verbose name* feature to each model field and build a simple template tag that can help you to get dinamicaly the verbose name of your fields i your templates

This template tag will try to get the model field's verbose name

```
# yourapp/templatetags/yourapp_extras.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def field_name(model, field):
    field_name = field

    if model:
        try:
            field_name = model._meta.get_field(field).verbose_name.title()
        except Exception as ex:
            print ex
    return field_name
```

And in your template you can display your field label as follow

```
# sometemplate.html
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load yourapp_extras %}

{% for field in form %}
  <div class="form-group">
    {% field_name model field.name %} <!-- here -->

    {% if form.is_bound %}
      {% if field.errors %}
        {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ error }}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
      {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if field.help_text %}
      <small class="form-text text-muted">
        {{ field.help_text }}
      </small>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```